# Not able to rate limit bull queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, redis, bull

in order to manage the traffic and effectively process a particular message, /
we have implemented a rate limited bull queue :-
but we are not able to acheive rate limiting .
Here is my implementation , but rate limiting in this queue is not working

```
const createNewQueue = async({ queueName, queueOpts = {}, defaultJobOpts = null, queueUrl = null }) =>{
try{
    console.log("createNewQueue fn called")
    if(defaultJobOpts){
        queueOpts.defaultJobOptions = defaultJobOpts
    }
    queueOpts['redis'] ={
      port:process.env.CS_REDIS_PORT,
      host:process.env.CS_REDIS_URL,
      password:process.env.CS_REDIS_PASSWORD
    }
    queueUrl = queueUrl ? queueUrl : redisUrl
    const newQueue = new Queue(queueName , queueOpts )
    console.log("\n\n\n queue created ------\n", newQueue)
    Queues[queueName] = newQueue
    return newQueue
}
catch(err){
    handleAppError({err})
}
```

}

```
const inputQueue = {
queueName: 'inputQueue',
processLeftJobs: true,
processOptions: {
  concurrency: 1
},
cleanQueue: true,
cleanQueueEvents: [
  'completed'
],
queueOpts:{
  limiter: {
    max: 1000,
    duration: 10000
  }
}
```

}

```
await createNewQueue(inputQueue)
```

Comment: Your function is `async`, but there is nothing asynchronous in your function; or am I missing something? Moreover, there is nothing in your code that does anything related to rate limiting: the `max` and `duration` values are nowhere used in the code you shared, so what do you expect?

Comment: @trincot , please see i have a object named inputQueue , where you can see values like max and duration under queueOpts...

Comment: Yes, I saw that object, but your code never uses them.

Comment: @trincot , see the last line where in i have written this :-
createNewQueue(inputQueue)

Comment: OK, I don't know how `Queue` works in Bull. I suppose there is documentation you can use. But ignoring that, I don't see anything that warrants the use of `async` / `await`.

Comment: As far as I understand you are creating queues, but you never put anything in those queues. Shouldn't you be creating *one* queue, and *add* jobs to it? See the `add` method, which returns a promise and would give sense to your `async`.

Comment: yes , i have not show job adding part here ..... My point was to show the configuration , if anything is wrong in that